# How to override the main wrapper on ngx-formly

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-formly

I need some help, I have a ionic 3 form.

I can't find the way to replace/override the main ionic wrapper. really need this to be able to use floating attribute on ionic.

If I don't do this, then, my problem is that my component gest wrapped twice.
i.e.

```
<custom-wrapper>
  <main-wrapper>
    <field/>
  </main-wrapper>
</custom-wrapper>
```

I need to do

```
<custom-wrapper>
  <field/>
</custom-wrapper>
```

Example code of my wrapper:

```
@component({
  selector: 'formly-wrapper-mm-form-field',
  template:` ++ <ng-template #fieldComponent></ng-template> ++ `,
})
```

Shows the following, that means that is applying the main wrapper:

[image]

I am adding this wrapper on the app.module as:

```
 FormlyModule.forRoot({
   wrappers: [
     { name: 'form-field', component: CustomWrapperComponent },
   ],
 }),
```

but is not doing the job.

Thank for the response.

Comment: the easy way to get rid of those wrappers is to rename your default wrapper to 'form-field': https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6d8efg (https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/1202#issuecomment-424846270). It works with latest ngx-formly as well